# npm errow while try using yeoman generator

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

hello i try to run npm install -g yo but i have got error :

```
    npm install -g yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yo

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: yo
npm ERR! No valid targets found.
npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:486:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:436:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:413:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:406:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:151:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /home
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.21
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: yo
npm ERR! message No valid targets found.
npm ERR! message Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /home
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.21
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/npm-debug.log
```

I havent got any idea what is wrong my npm version is 1.1.21 my node version is v0.6.18
Can you give me some advice what is wrong with that configuration ?

Comment: you are installing globally. are u running the command using a privileged user ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your version of Node.js and npm.

From the [Yeoman website](http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html):

> **Install prerequisites**
>
> Before installing Yeoman, you will need the following:
>
> - Node.js v0.10.x+
> - npm (which comes bundled with Node) v1.4.3+
> - git